# Filter ilightbox portfolio items based on URL query string parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a website that uses a portfolio with filters to define which images are displayed. The relavent JavaScript is (I believe) shown below:

```
    if( $element.hasClass( 'filterable-entries' ) ){
            $( '.cl-filters' ).on( 'click', 'button', function() {
                var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                if( filterValue != '*' )
                    $element.isotope({
                        filter: filterValue,
                        sortBy: 'random'
                    }); 
                else
                    $element.isotope({
                            filter: filterValue,
                            sortBy: 'original-order'
                    }); 
                            
                CL_FRONT.restartAnimations( $element );
                $element.isotope('arrange');
    
                $(this).parent().find('button.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');

            });
    }
```

The filters are using the 'data-filter' as mentioned above in the generated HTML (which I can't edit):

```
<div class="inner">
    <button data-filter="*" class="selected">All 2</button>
    <button data-filter=".portfolio_entries-abstract">Abstract</button>
    <button data-filter=".portfolio_entries-animal">Animal</button>
    <button data-filter=".portfolio_entries-famous-reproductions">Famous Reproductions</button>
    <button data-filter=".portfolio_entries-flower-tree">Flower & Tree</button>
    <button data-filter=".portfolio_entries-landscape">Landscape</button>
    <button data-filter=".portfolio_entries-modern-art">Modern Art</button>
    <button data-filter=".portfolio_entries-portrait">Portrait</button>
</div>
```

I need to make the `var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');` somehow take the value from the query string in order to apply the filter, **but without stopping the current button filters working**. So for example if the URL contains `?filter=abstract` (or any specific value) then it would apply the `.portfolio_entries-abstract` as the `filterValue`. However as the function appears to be triggered by a button click using `$( '.cl-filters' ).on( 'click', 'button', function() {` I'm not sure how this is possible.

The filter would also need to still apply the class `selected` to the appropriate filter button, and make sure it isn't applied to any of the others, as it currently does when using the buttons.

Example scenario: User visits the site with URL `mysite.com?filter=abstract` and is shown the filtered gallery with the relevant button highlighted by the .selected class. The user then changes the filter using the buttons to view a different category and carries on as normal - there is no need for the original filter to persist in any way.

This is a WordPress/WooCommerce site so is PHP based, but this JavaScript is included in the theme files as .js and not .php so I can't just use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`, not that I would know what to do with that in this context anyway...

Comment: Can you provide a basic and static demo?

Comment: @CarlosJiménez Not easily, as it's part of a WordPress/WooCommerce site theme. The above snippets are all I've been able to find regarding how it works and I don't know what other files are involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! :)

The logic is:

- Check if the user is loading the page for the first time this session using `sessionStorage`, and if not then just use the button filtering as normal rather than the URL filter.
- Get the query string using `URLSearchParams(window.location.search)`
- Get the specific parameter from the query string using `.has` from `URLSearchParams` (if it exists, otherwise just use the button filtering as normal)
- Then use the parameter value as both the filter (by appending the leading `.` to the value) and for the `.selected` CSS class (by using `$(document).find` and the parameter value from the query string.

  ```
  if( $element.hasClass( 'filterable-entries' ) ){     
   if (sessionStorage.alreadyRun2 != "true")
       var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
         if (params){
           if (params.has('filter') == true){  
               var filter = params.get('filter');                      
               var filterValue = "." + filter;
               if( filterValue != '*' ){
                   $element.isotope({
                       filter: filterValue,
                       sortBy: 'random'
                   }); 
               }
               else {
               $element.isotope({
                      filter: filterValue,
                      sortBy: 'original-order'
               }); 
               }

               CL_FRONT.restartAnimations( $element );
               $element.isotope('arrange');

               $(document).find('button.selected').removeClass('selected');
               $(document).find("[data-filter=" + CSS.escape(filterValue) + "]").addClass('selected');
          }
       } else {
           $( '.cl-filters' ).on( 'click', 'button', function() {
           var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
               if( filterValue != '*' ){
               $element.isotope({
                   filter: filterValue,
                   sortBy: 'random'
               }); 
               }
           else {
               $element.isotope({
                      filter: filterValue,
                      sortBy: 'original-order'
               });
           }

           CL_FRONT.restartAnimations( $element );
           $element.isotope('arrange');

           $(this).parent().find('button.selected').removeClass('selected');
           $(this).addClass('selected');
           });
       }
       sessionStorage.alreadyRun2 = "true";

       $( '.cl-filters' ).on( 'click', 'button', function() {
           var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
           if( filterValue != '*' )
               $element.isotope({
                   filter: filterValue,
                   sortBy: 'random'
               }); 
           else
               $element.isotope({
                       filter: filterValue,
                       sortBy: 'original-order'
               }); 

           CL_FRONT.restartAnimations( $element );
           $element.isotope('arrange');

           $(this).parent().find('button.selected').removeClass('selected');
           $(this).addClass('selected');

       });
   }
  ```

It needed adding in a few other places in the same file, but the logic is the same.